# How to log out from Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I would like to log in to Stack Overflow with a different account. I don't see the log out functionality anywhere.

The recent posts I found about logging out from Stack Overflow 1-2 years ago reference a [drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645233/how-do-i-log-out-of-stack-overflow) that doesn't seem to be there anymore.

I'm a little befuddled that I can't find this fairly simple functionality.

Also, I tried to post this on Stack Overflow Meta, but I didn't have enough Reputation.

Comment: In my browser the top-right header element (Stack Exchange logo) drops down to include a "log out" link.

Comment: You can also go to this URL https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout

Comment: Isn't it off topic?

Answer (score 1):

[Oy, found it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfYPa.png)

I don't know why but that was just not intuitive for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Top far right Click on the furthest tab under curent community on the right click Log out done job

Comment: Why is this downvoted ? just curious